# How to use hooks for central reporting feature?

Tags: karate

I have a scenario where I would like to use Karate in multiple projects which should share a common set of functions to update a central server with the status of the tests.

Parsing the results after a test run would be one option but I am also looking into options to using the hooks to send data to the server while the tests are running. This reporting layer should be hidden from people writing feature files, though.

Do you have ideas on how to best accommodate this with Karate?

Comment: I would prefer to put this functionality into a build pipeline. Having a central continuous delivery pipeline that is easy to extend and integrate is crucial to me. 

I don't think this is something you want to solve inside karate.

Comment: I second that and the tests run in a pipeline. I would still need to hook into Karate somehow during the test run to extract information about the status of the tests. Otherwise I am left with the report after execution. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you execute the `.features`? Are you using maven or gradle to run the tests? Are you using the standalone feature? 

Please, explain your current setup in more detail.

Comment: Hey Peter, I am using maven to run the tests and I am using the approach from  from https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java#L43 to get reports in the end.